# "-" is getting replaced by characters %2D1?

Tags: java

i entered below url in IE
https://localhost/myApp/4117-1Space/WebHome

when i do context.getURL().toString() in  my java class, i get string url as
https://localhost/myApp/4117%2D1Space/WebHome .

So here instead of character "-" i get %2D1. **Is there a way i get the exact word i.e 4117-1Space not 4117%2D1Space?**  Here i can replace programmatically
%2D1 with "-" for quick fix but there will other spcial characters also which will be replaced with  these kind of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do a

```
URLDecoder.decode(context.getURL().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

But you might be able to get the correct path directly through some other context method.

Comment: I forgot to add the string encoding parameter to my answer.  This one is better!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) like this

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(context.getURL().toString(),"UTF-8");
```